# Nodemailer: response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: email, gmail, credentials, nodemailer

With the shut down of [Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4ODNNBZ8xv2h43KdnGFcasVktUd-F2BKp8UvlXQsC4iIBAIlN1F_39pBeLIrLnOirfyeaeLNFsvRw4csoy4PwdUo8yfvA) by Google on May 30, 2022, using Gmail with nodemailer now throws an error that says `response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' + '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials`. The [Nodemailer docs](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/) appears to not be updated yet regarding this issue of Less secure apps but suggest to use another delivery provider. I used to just turn on LSA, store the credentials in an environment variable and let nodemailer do its thing, with this change, how can one still use gmail with nodemailer? There are no youtube tutorials to fix this yet and looking at the [google documentation](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833), it doesn't show nodemailer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved it by creating App password inside Google account. You must have 2-step verification actived.

[image: 2-step actived]

[image: App password created]

Comment: Have you tested that this works?  The point of this change is that google doesnt want us using login and password to access users accounts.   the better option is to use Xoauth2

Comment: Yes i did the test, have around 4 apis, after the correction all are fine

Comment: @GustavoPinto have tested and implemented it. It works. Thanks dude

Comment: @GustavoPinto It works by replacing the old with the new -16 characters- generated app password. Thanks for troubleshooting this!

Comment: Another tip. App passwords cannot be seen until you have already activated the 2-step verification. It appears below it after

Comment: `App passwords` is not visible even after 2-step verification is enabled, however you can still access it if you search for it in Google Account via search bar at the top.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [xoauth](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)  Nodemailer appears to support serval [oauth](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/) options

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: "user@example.com",
    clientId: "000000000000-xxx0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    clientSecret: "XxxxxXXxX0xxxxxxxx0XXxX0",
    refreshToken: "1/XXxXxsss-xxxXXXXXxXxx0XXXxxXXx0x00xxx",
    accessToken: "ya29.Xx_XX0xxxxx-xX0X0XxXXxXxXXXxX0x",
    expires: 1484314697598,
  },
});
```

Comment: I used OAuth2 to solve the issue
I followed this tutorial

https://dev.to/chandrapantachhetri/sending-emails-securely-using-node-js-nodemailer-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-g3a

Comment: Xoauth2 is the more secure option really.   There is no telling how long apps password will continue to work.   Im happy you got it working

Comment: above solution works. 
goto oauth playground and generate new refresh+access token with your clientID and Secret in the settings cog. 2-Step verification is not required.
must add oauth playground redirect to google console for Authorization.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Mail **>** *Settings* **>** *See all Settings* **>** *Forwarding and POP/IMAP*.
2. Enable *POP download:* **&** Enable *IMAP access:* (then save the settings). [Mail Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NfXF.png)
3. Open Your Gmail Account **>** *security* **>** *2-step verification*(enable it).
4. Go to *App Passwords* **>** *select device* **>** *select app(you can create any custom app)*.
5. Copy App Password and use it in your application.